# How to edit node module

Tags: node.js, react-native

I installed 'react-native-popup-dialog' by npm install.
And I moved it from 'npm module folder' to my main project folder'.
I read that module changing like below.
It works same.
However Although I changed some option inside of './popup', 
It's not changed nothing at all. 
So I wonder if the way of changing module like this is correct or not.

```
import Dialog, {
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogButton,
  ScaleAnimation,
} from 'react-native-popup-dialog';

--->

   import Dialog, {
      DialogTitle,
      DialogContent,
      DialogButton,
      ScaleAnimation,
    } from './popup';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module package.json there is a `main` prop mapped to `dist/index.js`.

In order to replicate from within your project you should import `from './popup/dist'`, `index.js` will be picked by default.

Answer (score 0):

never move a package from node_modules , use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) instead.